# Migrating Drupal 6 - 7 Content Type with optional file field, throws error

Tags: 7, migrations

I am currently working on migrating content from a Drupal 6 site to Drupal 7 and have started with a single content type for testing. The source content type has an optional image field, however if I try to import only those nodes with a file attached, I'm still running into issues.

Here is the source sql:

```
// Get source data:
//   1. node data
$query = Database::getConnection('default', 'extra')
  ->select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'created', 'changed', 'status', 'promote', 'sticky', 'language', 'tnid', 'comment'))
  ->condition('type', 'guest_lecturer');
//   2. node revision data (body, etc)
$query->join('node_revisions', 'nr', 'nr.vid = n.vid');
$query->fields('nr', array('body', 'format', 'log'));
//   3. extra fields
$query->join('content_type_guest_lecturer', 'nt', 'n.nid = nt.nid');
$query->fields('nt', array('field_lecturer_title_value', 'field_lecturer_teaser_value', 'field_lecturer_featured_value'));
//   4. files (only nodes with this file field set)
$query->join('files', 'f', 'f.fid = nt.field_lecturer_photo_fid');
$query->fields('f', array('filename'));
//   4. files (all nodes)
//$query->leftJoin('files', 'f', 'f.fid = nt.field_lecturer_photo_fid');
//$query->fields('f', array('filename'));
//   5. url alias
$query->join('url_alias', 'a', "a.src = CONCAT('node/', n.nid)");
$query->addField('a', 'dst');
```

And the field mapping:

```
// add field mappings
$this->addFieldMapping('title', 'title');
$this->addFieldMapping('created', 'created');
$this->addFieldMapping('changed', 'changed');
$this->addFieldMapping('status', 'status');
$this->addFieldMapping('promote', 'promote');
$this->addFieldMapping('sticky', 'sticky');
$this->addFieldMapping('language', 'language');
$this->addFieldMapping('tnid', 'tnid');
$this->addFieldMapping('comment', 'comment');
$this->addFieldMapping('uid')->defaultValue(1);
$this->addFieldMapping('revision')->defaultValue(FALSE);
$this->addFieldMapping('log', 'log');
$this->addFieldMapping('translate')->defaultValue(FALSE);
$this->addFieldMapping('revision_uid')->defaultValue(1);
$this->addFieldMapping('is_new')->defaultValue(FALSE);
$this->addFieldMapping('path', 'dst');

// add photo field mappings
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo', 'filename');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo:file_class')->defaultValue('MigrateFileUri');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo:language')->defaultValue('und');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo:destination_dir')->defaultValue('sites/default/files');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo:source_dir')->defaultValue('sites/all/modules/custom/azamara_migrate/files/lecturer_photo');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo:destination_file', 'filename');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo:file_replace')->defaultValue('FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo:preserve_files')->defaultValue(FALSE);
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo:alt')->defaultValue('');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_lecturer_photo:title')->defaultValue('');
```

And the error when I try to run the import:

```
22911   Error   PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {file_usage} (fid, module, type, id, count) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 92 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => file [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 ) in file_usage_add() (line 696 of /htdocs_svn/includes/file.inc).
22911   Error   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO {file_usage} (fid, module, type, id, count) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 92 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => file [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 1 ) (/htdocs_svn/includes/file.inc:696)
```

I can see that the [:db_insert_placeholder_3] is empty and is causing the problem, but how do I correct this?

Comment: Is there anyway you can download images using http url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this line from:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('is_new')->defaultValue(FALSE);
```

to:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('is_new')->defaultValue(TRUE);
```

fixes this specific issue.